# help to fine about CFG for $L=\{a^nb^mc^k:|n-m|=k\}$

Tags: context-free-grammar

Hi guys (and so sorry for my weak english).

I have a problem about this language:
$$L=\{a^nb^mc^k:|n-m|=k\}.$$

This language wants to produce some $k$ with $|n-m|$ but about another kind of this language it was **my attempt:**

for $n-m=k$ in  $L=\{a^nb^mc^k:n-m=k\}$ i wrote:
$$S\to e|A|Z\\
A\to aAc|ac\\
Z\to W1|W2\\
w1\to aW1b|ab\\
w2\to aW2c|aW1c$$

but for $|n-m|=k$ in $L=\{a^nb^mc^k:|n-m|=k\}$ have problem.
thanx.

Answer (score 0):

For lengths of strings it is better to rewrite into non-negative numbers.
Either $n\ge m$ and $n-m=k$ thus $n=m+k$, or  $m\ge n$ and $m-n=k$ thus $m=n+k$.
Now $L = \{ a^{m+k}b^mc^k \mid m,k\ge 0 \} \cup \{ a^nb^{n+k}c^k \mid n,k\ge 0 \} $.

Solve each of the two parts separately. You tried one of them, the other is symmetric.